# Проблема с AdMob "googleads.g.doubleclick.net"

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, admob

Запустили в пятницу приложение в релиз, настройки медиации AdMob правильные, в аккаунте тоже всё проверили, Test ads отрабатывал 10/10, но вот в релизе, люто сыпятся ошибки по рекламе стишл/ревард:

"Message: Error while connecting to ad server: Unable to resolve host "googleads.g.doubleclick.net": No address associated with hostnameCode: 0"

Сдк  все последнее, живая реклама показывается, но вот всего лишь 40%.
Остальные 60 отлетают по ошибкам:

- та что выше
- Network code 2
- unable to obtain a javascriptengine code 0

За нетворк и так ясно, а вот с другими двумя возникают вопросики, нашёл тред с гугл тим, но там они тоже не были решены.

Кто что может подсказать по этому делу?

Comment: `Unable to resolve host` - похоже что приложению не дали разрешение на доступ в интернет.

Comment: `unable to obtain a javascriptengine` - возможно проблема с WebView на каком-то конкретном девайсе, группируйте ошибки по девайсам

Comment: @aepot Вы имеете ввиду пользователь сам обрубил инет?
Что удалось нагуглить самому, проблема с DNS по типу блокировщика, но это немного не то.
Манифест учитывает ситуацию с инетом)
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />